# The cursor caret moves to beginning when innerHTML property is used in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

Here i am using innerHTML property inside a contenteditable div.The problem is whenever i am trying to edit the content,the caret cursor moves to the beginning and reverses the whole text.What should i do to move the caret to end position like normal edits?

MY HTML CODE :

```
<div #editor class="editor" 
              style=" max-height: 200px;" 
              [innerHTML]="blogData.description"
              (input)="onChange()"
              (input)="blogData.description=$event.target.innerHTML"
              name="blogData.description"
              contenteditable></div>
```

[image]

The above screenshot shows the difference,Actually i am typing "this is",because of the cursor in the beginning the content looks like this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is happening in `onChange` event ?

Comment: The onchange event is just consoling the datas and in the console.log i am getting the same output like in the image

Comment: I guess the cursor is moving to start because - 1. you are setting `[innerHTML]` as `blogData.description` and 2. in `(input)` event you are setting `blogData.description`. So it is behaving like `set` in input event and `get` in `[innerHTML]` property, so while it sets the value, the cursor moves back to start

Comment: Yes you are correct,that s what i am doing. Here i need to get and set the value at the same time so that causes the error so how to override this error?

Comment: You should `set` the `value` only at beginning, in JS not in html. Similarly, update the value in JS variable when the value is changed.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? I'm also having the same issue

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer did you resolve it??