# The cursor caret moves to beginning when innerHTML property is used as getter in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, innerhtml, angular11

Here i am using innerHTML property inside a contenteditable div.The problem is whenever i am trying to edit the content,the caret cursor moves to the beginning and reverses the whole text.What should i do to move the caret to end position like normal edits? I'm totally stuck, please help me on this.

```
<div class="box" #model contenteditable (keyup)="updateModel(model.innerText)" [innerHTML]="content | linkify"></div>
    <span [innerHTML]="content | linkify"></span>

    updateModel(value: any) {
    this.content = value;
  }
```

This one i tried actually, here the [innerHTML] property for html parsing. The issue is on cursor caret getting back to beginning.

What i need to achieve:

input section:- this is a link: www.testlink.com(link should be displayed as hyper link, i achieved it by using 'linkify' pipe.)

problem:- when i typing 'hello': it returns like 'olleh'(because of the cursor caret getting reversed.)

[Here's the open question related to it, same one i also need to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318302/the-cursor-caret-moves-to-beginning-when-innerhtml-property-is-used-in-angular)

Comment: Please provide your own minimal reproducible example as part of your question, not just an external link.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton like you said i updated, can you please help me on this!

Comment: What does `updateModel(model.innerText)` do?

Comment: It's just updating the content value.

Comment: Can you show the code please, so it can be reproduced. Even better, you could create a stackblitz.

Comment: I updated it in the question.